Deal with line break while using IMPORTXML in Google Sheet
I'm trying to fetch some data from this web page: https://www.rendimentibtp.it/quotazione-btp/IT0005439275
Everything's good, until I come up to the "scadenza" <div> (screenshot here), where are shown 2 dates, separated by a </br>.

With the formula =IMPORTXML("https://www.rendimentibtp.it/quotazione-btp/IT0005439275";"(//*[@id='scadenza'])") I get the twho dates in the same row, separated by an empty cell (A2 and C2).

While my need is to fetch them in two different cells in the same column (A2 and A3)

Do you have any idea how to fix this?
Many thanks


You may try:
=tocol(<your_importxml_formula> ,1)


Thanks, it works putting elements in a column, but I still have the blank cell between the two dates (so now dates are in A1 and A3).

https://i.sstatic.net/IhDeDkWk.png

Thanks, I got it. I had to change the "," to a ";" given my language. It works, thanks!
